# NullPointerException into a servlet-filter

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, servlet-filters

Well, after my older questions:

[Are there some issue at inserting some check into template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062757/are-there-some-issue-at-inserting-some-check-into-template)

and

[Is it a good idea to filter inside a JSF template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975228/is-it-a-good-idea-to-filter-inside-a-jsf-template)

I'm writing the filter, but sometimes (not even at the same point) the application returns `NulPointerException` at this line:

```
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

and I don't understand why...
The full code for my filter is:

```
    @WebFilter(filterName = "RolesFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"},
     initParams = {
      @WebInitParam(name = "param", value = "value")})

    public class RolesFilter implements Filter {

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
            // NOOP.
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            UserBean user = (session.getAttribute("userBean") != null) ? (UserBean) session.getAttribute("userBean") : null;
                String uri=request.getRequestURI();

    if(!uri.endsWith("index.xhtml") && !uri.endsWith(".css") && !uri.endsWith(".js")  && !uri.endsWith("template.xhtml"))
    {
            if (user == null || user.getCognome() == null) 
                response.sendRedirect("/cdg/faces/index.xhtml");
            else {
                String app=uri.substring(0,uri.lastIndexOf("/"));
                app=app.substring(app.lastIndexOf("/")+1,app.length());
                HashMap> privilegi= (HashMap)user.getPrivilegi();
                Long idAppl=((AbstractController)session.getAttribute(app+"Controller")).getIdApplicazione();
                Short[] privPoss=((AbstractController)session.getAttribute(app+"Controller")).getPrivilegiPossibili();
    //--- if privPoss has only 3 value the application is a classic application with 2 roles so I can use a generic check, if the number is different I must do a specific check.
                            if(privilegi.get(idAppl)!=null && privPoss.length==3)
                            {
         if((privilegi.get(idAppl)).get(privPoss[0])==null && (uri.endsWith("Edit.xhtml") || uri.endsWith("Create.xhtml")))
                response.sendRedirect("/cdg/faces/index.xhtml");
            } else {
                                if(idAppl==35)
                                {
                                    ProgettiController pc=(session.getAttribute("progettiController")!=null) ? (ProgettiController)session.getAttribute("progettiController") : null;
         if(privilegi.get(idAppl).get(privPoss[1])==null && uri.endsWith("progetti/Create.xhtml"))
                response.sendRedirect("/cdg/faces/index.xhtml"); 
         else if(uri.endsWith("progetti/Edit.xhtml")
     && (!privilegi.get(idAppl).get(privPoss[5]).equals("0") && !UserBean.isInString(pc.getSelected().getIdAzienda().getId()+"",privilegi.get(idAppl).get(privPoss[5]),"#")))
                response.sendRedirect("/cdg/faces/index.xhtml"); 
         else if((uri.endsWith("attivita/Create.xhtml") || uri.endsWith("attivita/Create.xhtml"))
     &&(!pc.getSelected().getIdResponsabile().equals(user.getUtente())) )
                response.sendRedirect"/cdg/faces/index.xhtml"); 
         else if(uri.endsWith("attivita/Edit.xhtml")
     && (!privilegi.get(idAppl).get(privPoss[2]).equals("0") && !UserBean.isInString(pc.getSelected().getIdAzienda().getId()+"",privilegi.get(idAppl).get(privPoss[2]),"#")))
                response.sendRedirect("/cdg/faces/index.xhtml"); 
         else if((uri.endsWith("progettiQualifica/Create.xhtml") || uri.endsWith("progettiQualifica/Create.xhtml"))
     && (!pc.getSelected().getIdResponsabile().equals(user.getUtente())))
                response.sendRedirect("/cdg/faces/index.xhtml"); 
         else if((uri.endsWith("progettiSchede/Create.xhtml") || uri.endsWith("attivita/Create.xhtml"))
     && (!pc.getSelected().getIdResponsabile().equals(user.getUtente())))
                response.sendRedirect("/cdg/faces/index.xhtml"); 
    }
                                else if(idAppl==2)
                                {
                                    RisorseController rc=(session.getAttribute("risorseController")!=null) ? (RisorseController)session.getAttribute("risorseController") : null;
         if(privilegi.get(idAppl).get(privPoss[0])==null && (uri.endsWith("Create.xhtml") || uri.endsWith("Edit.xhtml")))
                response.sendRedirect("/cdg/faces/index.xhtml"); 
         else if(uri.endsWith("Edit.xhtml")
     && (!rc.getSelected().equals(user.getUtente())))
                response.sendRedirect("/cdg/faces/index.xhtml"); 
                                }
                                }
                            }
        } 
                chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            // NOOP.
        }

    }
```

Where could the problem be?

well, before this answer I delete a row from my code and now the filter seems work correctly, could this row cause the problem?

```
    System.out.println("The uri is:"+request.getRequestURI());
```

it was after the first if in doFilter method...
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling the `doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)` method with `null` value as the third parameter.

Did you check that?

Comment: It does not change the question.

Comment: If he is passing in `null`, it would give `NullPointerException` rather consistently, isn't it?

Comment: @KARASZI István : emh... sorry but I don't understand your question, or better, doesn't the filter call automatically from application without a my specific call to it? If it is correct, how could I call it without a parameter?

Comment: Not without a parameter, but with a parameter with `null` value.

Comment: @KARASZI István : ok, but my question remains without answer... if I never call it directly, how can I set a parameter as not null? :)

Comment: The stack trace can help you out.